# Math.max returns NaN in case of null values

Tags: javascript, controller, component, math

I am a new one in javascript and there is a case. I have a controller with many input values and I want to get the maximum value of them. I use `var getMax = Math.max(field1__c,field2__c,field3__c,..etc)`, but if one of these fields has a null value, function returns me a NaN. How can I achieve this? I think of creating multiple if(!field1__c){ field1__c = 0; }, but there are 13 fields that need to be checked, and I don't think that this is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can handle this several different ways.

You could use || to replace the empty/null/etc values with zeroes:

```
Math.max(field1__c||0,field2__c||0,...);
```

Or you can make an array, filter out non-numbers, and call the method dynamically:

```
let values = [field1__c,field2__c,field3__c,...].filter(value => Number.isFinite(value));
let maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, values);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked as I wanted!!